# magento generate white space image to fit the thumb

Tags: magento-1.9

I got a problem with magento image generator process. Image will be placed with 3 size of thumb for homepage, listing page and detail page.

- Homepge , product thumb will be 365x265 px
- Listing page, product thumb will be 225x190 px
- Detail page, product thumb will be 350x241 px

At detail page customer can click on thumb to see lightbox with full image.

My Problem is that images on each page not ratio, **but I want magento resize and crop with proper size (full image on thumb), I mean can show partial image just fit to the thumb with no white space on image**.

How can I do this ? is it not default by mangeto ?

My website:
Homepage

stellaanddust.com/

Listing Page

stellaanddust.com/new-arrivals.html

Detail Page

stellaanddust.com/women/simple-product-49.html

Please guide,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `keepFrame(false)` to remove white spaces around the images and `resize(value in pixel)` to resize the images. 
**Example Code Snippet :**

```
$_imageUrl = $this->helper('catalog/image')
                    ->init($_product, 'image', $_image->getFile())
                    ->keepFrame(false)
                    ->constrainOnly(true)
                    ->resize(1200);
```

Comment: work great !! thks :) but it resize to show full image. Could you suggest me how to resize into best fit and crop. thks

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure what are trying to say by best fit, you can use different images in Magento like image or small_image or thumbnail. May this will help you.